# Error: argument is not a character vector

Tags: r, tm

Continuing my text mining analysis I got the error
namely I try clean corpus

```
my.stopwords=read.table("path to my stopword list") stops=as.character(my.stopwords$V1)
generateCorpus <- function(df, stops = c()) {
  #corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df))

  myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df))
  if (Sys.info()['sysname']=="Darwin"){
    -        myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8-MAC', sub='byte'))   
    +        myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8-MAC', sub='byte')))   
  }
  if (Sys.info()['sysname']=="Windows"){
    -        myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))  
    +        myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte")))
  }

  # convert to lower case
  cat("Converting to lowercase... ")
  -    myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
  +    myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  cat("done!\n")
  # remove numbers
  cat("Removing digits and URLs... ")
  -    myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
  +    myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(removeNumbers))
  # remove URLS
  removeURL <- function(x) gsub('"(http.*) |(http.*)$|\n', "", x)
  cat("done!\n")
  -    myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeURL) 
  +    myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(removeURL))

}
my.corpus <- generateCorpus(myCorpus, stops)
```

And as a result i got this message

> Error in enc2utf8(x) : argument is not a character vector

What does it mean?

update

```
> if (Sys.info()['sysname']=="Windows"){
+            myCorpus <- tm_map( myCorpus, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(as.character(x)), sub = "byte")
+     )
+     myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(as.character(x)), sub = "byte")))
+   }
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I think main problem in content

```
Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "character"
Called from: content(x)
Browse[1]> 

function (x) 
UseMethod("content", x)
```

Who decided this problem?

Comment: Maybe try `read.table("path to my stopword list", as.is=TRUE)`. I suspect that you have factor variables somewhere that should be character. This line is the first place to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `tm_map` does not iterate over characters, but documents. This can be seen by

```
data(crude)
tm_map(crude, function(x) browser())
```

and then, inspecting x,

```
x
#<<PlainTextDocument>>
#...
enc2utf8(x)
#error in enc2utf8(x) : argumemt is not a character vector
```

Maybe it suffices to apply `as.character` first, that is,

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(
    myCorpus, 
    function(x) {
        content(x) <- iconv(enc2utf8(as.character(content(x))), sub = "byte")
        return(x)
    }
)
```

might do the trick.

Comment: I tried do this, but i got the error, please look at update on my post, it error only for windows. What do you think?

Comment: I am not a user of the `tm` package, but it looks as if `content_transformer` does not expect a character but a different class. Hence you may need to wrap the output of iconv.

Comment: hm, in this string same error > myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: "Hence you may need to wrap the output of iconv".  could you show me how do this please

Comment: I just wanted to point out how you could debug. I am not a `tm` user (yet) hence I can not give you a complete solution. I edited the answer, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in this site
http://www.listendata.com/2014/11/create-wordcloud-with-r.html

I changed any strings, and after, i get the needed result

```
removeURL <- function(x) gsub('"(http.*) |(http.*)$|\n', "", x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeURL)

kb.tf <- list(weighting = weightTf, stopwords  = stopwords,
              removePunctuation = TRUE,
              tolower = TRUE,
              minWordLength = 4,
              removeNumbers = TRUE, stripWhitespace = TRUE,
              stemDocument= TRUE)

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument) 

generateCorpus <- function(df, kb.tf = c()) {
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df))
}
my.corpus <- generateCorpus(myCorpus, kb.tf)
```

I think i did contribute, because i saw analogical posts and this problem was hot